# Remove pagination from order listing in frontend customer account?

Tags: magento2, customer-account, pagination

I want list all the orders in a single page. how I remove pagination from my orders page in my account dashboard.

Comment: Are you talking about Sales order history page oR Customer dashboard page?

Comment: My orders page under customer dashboard.. order sales history

Comment: @AmitBera    on the Customer dashboard page, there is no pagination, it only shows 5 orders under dashboard(My Account), is there any limit on the dashboard orders?I only see 5 orders

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can remove pagination from using the events  `layout_generate_blocks_after`.

**Run an observer on these events and remove the block `sales.order.history.pager` from layout which is responsible for pagination.**

**events.xml code:**

**Location** `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Amit Bera
 * @copyright https://www.amitbera.com/
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd"> 
    <event name="layout_generate_blocks_after">
        <observer name="remove_pager_block" 
                  instance="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Observer\RemovePagerFromSalesOrderHistoryObserver"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Observer code:**

**Location** 
*app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Observer/RemovePagerFromSalesOrderHistoryObserver.php*

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class RemovePagerFromSalesOrderHistoryObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $layout = $observer->getLayout();
        $action = $observer->getFullActionName();
        if ($action !== 'sales_order_history') {
            return;
        }
        $block = $layout->getBlock('sales.order.history');
        if ($block) {
            $layout->unsetElement('sales.order.history.pager');
        }
    }

}
```

***But as layout `layout_generate_blocks_after` is run later after the limit set so,it showing 10 order on the page***.

*So, in case, i have used a trick where using a plugin I have tried to reset the page item limit.*

Create a plugin on Class `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager` and using after plugin `getLimit()` i have modified  ***limit of the current page to 5000***;

**Plugin di.xml**

**Location:** `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/frontend/di.xml`

**and code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="reset_limit_sales_order" 
                        sortOrder="10" 
                        type="{Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\PagePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**PLugin Class**

*app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/Plugin/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/PagePlugin.php*

and code is:

```
<?php
namespace {Vendor}\{Modulename}\Plugin\Magento\Theme\Block\Html;

class PagePlugin {
    public function afterGetLimit(
     \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $subject,
      $result      
    )
    {
      if($subject->getNameInLayout() != 'sales.order.history.pager')
      {
          return $result;
      }
      // if sales.order.history.pager then set page limit=5000;
      return 5000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its working but only taking 10 orders. I want to show all order under that customer. Please help. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sure let me check

Comment: Works fine... Thank you so much for your support @AmitBera

Answer (score 0):

Rather than modifying the order history block is it not better to create a custom block (or a viewModel) and get all orders from the `OrderRepositoryInterface`?

```
    public function __construct(
    Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
    Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteriaBuilder,
    Magento\Customer\Model\Session\Proxy $customerSession
) {
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    $this->criteriaBuilder = $criteriaBuilder;
    $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
}


public function getOrders()
{
    if (!($customerId = $this->customerSession->getCustomerId())) {
        return [];
    }
    if (empty($this->orders)) {
        $criteria = $this->criteriaBuilder->addFilter('customer_id', $customerId)->create();
        $this->orders = $this->orderRepository->getList($criteria)->getItems();
    }

    return $this->orders;
}
```