# How to remove pagination(pager) from My Orders section in My Account (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, orders, pagination, pager

I am showing all orders, in `My orders` section of `My Account`, when the list of orders gets more than 10 Magento creates a pagination().

How to remove that pagination.

I am trying to remove `pagination` and added `LOAD MORE` button which shows rest of the orders.

Is there any admin setting to remove `pagination`.

I found this piece of code in `My Orders` phtml

```
 <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

[image]

Comment: You can comment above code and pager will gone!

Comment: @summu Try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262641/remove-pagination-from-order-listing-in-frontend-customer-account